# Is there an easy way to prepopulate webform field default values from profile2 field values?

Tags: webforms, tokens, users

We are working on major project where client wants webform fields to be prepopulated from profile2 fields. Webform version 3.17

Is there any way to create tokens or similar from profile2 fields to be used on webform default values?

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade to webform 4.x?  4.x has improved token support.

Answer (score 1):

hook_form_alter(){
//and set default values form profile2_load_by_user();
}

Answer (score 0):

In version 4.x webforms has token support and you can add fields from profile2.

For example, if you have a profile called chef and a field called (field_check_age), you should use this token: [current-user:profile-chef:field-chef-age]